# MS SQL DATE manipulation with Season of the Year

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table which includes the columns Season and Academic_Year.  Academic_Year is type int.  Season can be Spring, Summer or Fall.

- Fall 2016 is from 1 Sep 2016 to 31 Dec 2016.
- Spring 2016 is from 1 Jan 2017 to 31 Mar 2017 (not a typo - the Academic Year 2016 is from Sep 2016 to Aug 2017)
- Summer 2016 is from 1 Apr 2017 to 31 Aug 2017

I need to select rows when getdate() is between a number of days before and after the start of the Season, in pseudo code

```
WHERE 
    ( getdate() > 31/3/16 AND getdate() < 31/9/16 AND Season = 'Autumn' AND Academic_Year = 2016 )
    OR ( getdate() > 31/9/16 AND getdate() < 31/1/17 AND Season = 'Spring' AND Academic_Year = 2016 )
    OR ( getdate() > 31/12/16 AND getdate() < 31/4/17 AND Season = 'Summer' AND Academic_Year = 2016 )
```

My problem is creating the date for comparison with getdate().  I need to combine a string - '31/3/' - with an int - Academic_Year, and create a date.

The solution does not need to be efficient but it does need to work on 2008 and later sql server versions.

Comment: I don't see what your pseudo code has to do with your "My problem is..." paragraph.   Can you give an example of existing data and desired results from that data?

Comment: doesn't help you figure out what you're going to do when the `Academic_Year` is 2016 but you're in a season that stretches into 2017..

Comment: Expand your table to have a `Season_Start_Date` and `Season_End_Date` field.

Comment: @JamieD77 - it is a school related application so the next Academic year is known as '2016', runs from September 2016 to July 2017 and includes Fall (or Autumn in the UK) 2016, Spring 2017 and Summer 2017

Comment: @Ahiggins - unfortunately, this has to run on 3rd party computers (using a batch file calling sqlcmd to select the required data).  I'm not able to modify the table.

Answer (score 0):

SQL will allow this conversion if you just concatenate the `varchar`s and tell it to convert to `date`.  For example:

```
declare @year int = 2016
declare @date varchar(10) = '3/31'

select cast(@date + '/' + cast(@year as varchar(4)) as date)
```

You have to cast the `integer` year to `varchar` to combine it with the other `varchar`, but you can then cast the entire thing to a `date` (or `datetime`) once you have a recognized date format.

Comment: As a sidenote, you may want to investigate the `dateadd` and `datediff` functions - they may be easier than manually entering the dates you want to use for your checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can form your date by doing by using concatenation of the string and year.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), Academic_Year) + '-03-31'
```

Once you have the date string you could use the date functions to manipulate it further if necessary.

Comment: - thanks for this - I had experimented with this sort of construction but had been trying '31-03-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), Academic_Year) which didn't work. 
Have +1'd but not enough reputation yet for it to show :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (GETDATE() > CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),Academic_Year) + '-03-31'
    AND GETDATE() < CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),Academic_Year) + '-09-30'
    AND Season = 'Autumn') etc
```

worked for me.  The trick was adding '-03-31' rather than preceeding with '31-03-'.  Thanks @kicken